# Mathematically correct definition of own calculus

Tags: number-theory

I'm looking for an example of a complete definition of a custom calculus I could learn from to mathematically correct define my own calculus consinsting of:

- objects: a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaa, ... , b, bb, bbb, bbbb, etc
- operations on those objects: + , - , *; eg: a+a = aa
- etc...

Basically I want to remap natural numbers and the basic functions for my own needs and am looking for good resource to define a mathematically sound framework.

Comment: I think what you want to define is not a calculus, but an algebraic structure. Calculus is about differentiation and integration. Algebra is about adding and multiplying.

Comment: Look into abstract or universal algebra. Magmas, monoids, semigroups, groups, rings, semirings, fields, modules, preorders, posets, lattices, whatever your heart desires.

Comment: @celtschk: *Differential* calculus and *integral* calculus are about differentiation and integration.

Comment: Agreed - lets not forget that propositional calculus and predicate calculus have nothing to do with differentiation and integration.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you want to treat natural numbers as strings and you are thinking of typographical theory of natural numbers. These links might turn out helpfull [[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language), [[2]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). Second source provides an example of something you have had in mind I guess. In particular, one example of typographical system of natural numbers is presented in [Goedel, Escher, Bach" An Eternal Golden Braid](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0465026567) - the system is called [TNT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_Number_Theory).

Answer (score 0):

Write out the **signature** of your theory: A list of names of constants, names of functions (and their arity), names of relations and their arity.

Then list the **axioms** of the theory: logical sentences which must hold.

Then produce some **model** of your theory: Give some set and an interpretation that translates every name of a constant to an element of the set. Every function of a function on this set.. etc.

That a model exists proves the consistency of your theory (at least, it's consistent if your metatheory is).

---

Example.

Signature $(T,F,not,and,or)$. Axioms $\forall x, not(not(x))=x$ and $\forall x y, and(T,F)=T$ etc.. Model: {0,1} interpretation $T \mapsto 1$, $F \mapsto 0$, $not \mapsto $ the $1-x$ function, $and \mapsto$ the $xy$ function. This proves the theory of boolean algebra is consistent.